# How to align a FAB to bottom-center in nativebase?

Tags: react-native, native-base

How to align a FAB to bottomCenter and topCenter in NativeBase ?

```
<Fab direction="up" containerStyle={{ }} style={{ backgroundColor: '#5067FF' }} position="bottomCenter" > 
    <Icon name="gas-station" /> 
</Fab>
```

bottomCenter in the FAB is not working.. Is there any way to arrange FAB in bottom center

There is option available for topLeft,topRight,bottomLeft,bottomRight.But nothing can be seen for bottomCenter/topCenter

Comment: please explain more, and put some code of your attempt.

Comment: Add `containerStyle={{left: '50%'}}` and change `position="bottomLeft"` or `position="bottomRight"` for bottomCenter and `position="topLeft"` or `position="topRight"` for topCenter

Comment: @akhilxavier It helps.. Thank you

Comment: @akhilxavier: It worked for me also. Thanks. You can post this comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add containerStyle={{left: '50%'}} and change position="bottomLeft" or position="bottomRight" for bottomCenter and position="topLeft" or position="topRight" for topCenter

Comment: After copying this post from the comments without giving attribution, you should mark it as community wiki. See: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat) and [What is the approach to deal with a blatant copy of the answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272199/what-is-the-approach-to-deal-with-a-blatant-copy-of-the-answer)